# How to re-order sprite in Cocos2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, z-order

I would like to know how to change the z-order of a sprite in cocos2D on touch.

What I am looking for is something more complex then just a z-order change from 0 to 1 on touch, but for it to then change from 1 to 2 and 3 to 4 and so on.

So if a sprite is on z:0 to start with on each subsequent touch it will go up by 1. (e.g. 1, 2, 3 ...)

Answer (score 1):

use CCNode reoredChild
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_c_node.html#ab58888d399872a970aba610c1634a117